# Create comparator from another of different type

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have a very simple helper class that looks something like:

```
private static class IntIdx {
    int val;
    int idx;
    IntIdx(int val, int idx) {
        this.val = val;
        this.idx = idx;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return val;
    }
    public int getIdx() {
        return idx; 
    }
}
```

And I use a comparator that sorts it by value then by index:

```
static public List<Integer> decode(List<Integer> al) {

    final Comparator<IntIdx> idxComp = Comparator
        .comparingInt(IntIdx::getValue)
        .thenComparingInt(IntIdx::getIdx);

 ...[other code]...
}
```

I now have a situation where the values must be sorted in a different order, so I want to allow the caller to pass in a Comparator<Integer> for the value part. The problem is I don't know how to create such a comparator using similar syntax to above. Because the caller doesn't need to be aware of the implementation details, they are not passing a Comparator<IntIdx>, they are passing a Comparator<Integer> and I don't know how to chain together comparators for IntIdx using a comparator for Integer.

I can write something like:

```
static public List<Integer> decode(List<Integer> al, Comparator<Integer> valComp) {

    final Comparator<IntIdx> testComp = (i1, i2) -> {
            int r = valComp.compare(i1.getValue(), i2.getValue());
            if (r != 0) {
                return r;
            }
            return Integer.compare(i1.getIdx(), i2.getIdx());
        };

 ...[other code]...
}
```

which should work, but it feels much messier than what I currently have. Is this the best way of writing this? Is there any way to write the above is the nice `Comparator.comparing...` syntax in the current implementation?

It feels like there should be something like the following (which I understand doesn't work)

```
final Comparator<IntIdx> testComp = Comparator.compare(valComp.compare(IntIdx::getValue)).thenComparingInt(IntIdx::getIdx)
```

or

```
final Comparator<IntIdx> testComp = valComp.comparing(IntIdx::getValue).thenComparingInt(IntIdx::getIdx);
```

although I can't find anything like that in the Comparator documentation or my Google/SO searches.

I assume this is a relatively common thing and I just don't know the correct terminology to search for. I look forward to face-palming when the answer is revealed.

If the caller passed in a Comparator<IntIdx>, it would be easy to chain it together like

```
final Comparator<IntIdx> iiComp = valComp.thenComparingInt(IntIdx::getIdx);
```

but that's not my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing `Comparator` by writing a convoluted multiline lambda is error-prone. Leveraging Java 8 factory methods is always a preferred way to define a `Comparator`, you simply need to use another static method.

Replace `comparingInt()` with [`comparing(Function, Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function,java.util.Comparator)), which allows to provide a Comparator that should be used to compare the result produced by the specified Function:

```
static public List<Integer> decode(List<Integer> al,
                                   Comparator<Integer> valComp) {
    
    final Comparator<IntIdx> idxComp = Comparator
        .comparing(IntIdx::getValue, valComp)
        .thenComparingInt(IntIdx::getIdx);
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I wanted. (And I am facepalming that I didn't find that method on my own.)